# Itálico nos títulos dos painéis no facet_wrap()

Tags: r, ggplot2

Estou com dificuldades em formatar nomes de espécies em itálico no título dos painéis com o argumento `facet_wrap` no `ggplot2`. Segue exemplo:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mpg, aes(x=displ, y=hwy)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE, colour="black") +
  facet_wrap(~ trans)
```

Nesse exemplo temos como resultado 10 painéis, cada um com um título, que são as variáveis em minha tabela original de dados. Como colocar esses títulos em itálico?

Comment: Muuuito obrigado Marcus! Eu mesmo fazendo a pergunta aqui, continuei buscando descobrir, e já tinha achado que o caminho seria pelo strip.text, só não tinha acertado a formatação do código.... Muito obrigado mesmo!!

Comment: É muito bom saber que a minha resposta te ajudou de alguma forma. Por isso, considere [votar e aceitar a resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta), de modo que, no futuro, outras pessoas que passarem pelo mesmo problema tenham uma referência para solucioná-lo.

Answer (score 5):

No help da função `ggplot2::theme`, é possível encontrar o argumento `strip.text`. A descrição dele é a seguinte: `facet labels (element_text(); inherits from text)`. Portanto, basta alterar a opção de `strip.text` dentro de `theme` para obter o resultado desejado:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mpg, aes(x=displ, y=hwy)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE, colour="black") +
  facet_wrap(~ trans) +
  theme(strip.text = element_text(face = "italic"))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]